# How do I polyfill the "process" Node module in the Vite dev server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, polyfills

In my Vite project, I am depending on a module that makes use of the `process` Node global in one of its functions. I don't call this function from my code, but the *Vite dev* server still gives me this error when I import the module:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Interestingly, I don't see this error when I create a production build.

How can I polyfill `process` with a no-op so that the Vite dev server stops failing?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today in a React project using rollup + vite and here's how I solved it, using [this Medium piece by Fabiano Taioli](https://medium.com/@ftaioli/using-node-js-builtin-modules-with-vite-6194737c2cd2).

### Vite needs Node.js polyfills

You need to add some polyfill plugins to allow Node globals, such as `process`. Fortunately, you can simply edit (or create) the `vite.config.js`.

#### Example `vite.config.js`

Below is an example which includes using `NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin` to polyfill `process`. It also includes many other node globals so remove at your leisure.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';
import ReactPlugin from 'vite-preset-react';
import rollupNodePolyFill from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // This Rollup aliases are extracted from @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill,
      // see https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins/blob/master/node-modules-polyfill/src/polyfills.ts
      // process and buffer are excluded because already managed
      // by node-globals-polyfill
      util: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util',
      sys: 'util',
      events: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events',
      stream: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream',
      path: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path',
      querystring: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs',
      punycode: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode',
      url: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url',
      string_decoder: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder',
      http: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
      https: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
      os: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os',
      assert: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert',
      constants: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants',
      _stream_duplex:
        'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex',
      _stream_passthrough:
        'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough',
      _stream_readable:
        'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable',
      _stream_writable:
        'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable',
      _stream_transform:
        'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform',
      timers: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers',
      console: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console',
      vm: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm',
      zlib: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib',
      tty: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty',
      domain: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain',
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    ReactPlugin({
      injectReact: false,
    }),
    rollupNodePolyFill(),
  ],
});
```

### Development dependencies required

To make the above example work as is you'll need to add some dependencies. In particular:

```bash
yarn add --dev vite-preset-react
yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , util_1.promisify) is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is adding to your index.html

```
<script type="module">
  import process from 'process';
  window.process = process;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [node-stdlib-browser](https://github.com/niksy/node-stdlib-browser#vite), and it works really well for me.

And the following is my final `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'
import nodeStdlibBrowser from 'node-stdlib-browser'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import#configuration
        AutoImport({
            dts: 'src/auto-import.d.ts',
            imports: ['vue', 'vue-router'],
            eslintrc: {
                enabled: true,
            },
        }),
        // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#configuration
        Components({
            dts: 'src/components.d.ts',
        }),
        // https://github.com/niksy/node-stdlib-browser#vite
        {
            ...inject({
                global: [require.resolve('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/shim'), 'global'],
                process: [require.resolve('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/shim'), 'process'],
                Buffer: [require.resolve('node-stdlib-browser/helpers/esbuild/shim'), 'Buffer'],
            }),
            enforce: 'post',
        },
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), ...nodeStdlibBrowser },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            target: 'esnext', // Enable Big integer literals
        },
    },
    build: {
        target: 'esnext', // Enable Big integer literals
        commonjsOptions: {
            transformMixedEsModules: true, // Enable @walletconnect/web3-provider which has some code in CommonJS
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use 'esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node' plugin.
https://npm.io/package/esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node
This solved the problem for me, and NO NEEDED of manually adding and assigning `global = window` in script tag.