# Promisify is not a function (Vue.js, Vite, TypeScript, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, vue.js, vite

While attempting to connect to my MongoDB instance in Atlas, I came across several errors stemming from Vite not using Node's built in modules such as `events`, `util`, `process`, etc. After looking into the issue, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221740/how-do-i-polyfill-the-process-node-module-in-the-vite-dev-server) to some of the errors I was getting, but not all of them.

Here is my `vite.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      util: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
      sys: "util",
      events: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events",
      stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
      path: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path",
      querystring: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs",
      punycode: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode",
      url: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url",
      string_decoder: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder",
      http: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
      https: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
      os: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os",
      assert: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert",
      constants: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants",
      _stream_duplex:
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex",
      _stream_passthrough:
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough",
      _stream_readable:
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable",
      _stream_writable:
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable",
      _stream_transform:
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform",
      timers: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers",
      console: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console",
      vm: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm",
      zlib: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib",
      tty: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty",
      domain: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain",
      buffer: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/buffer-es6",
      process: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6",
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [rollupNodePolyFill()],
    },
  },
});
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: util_1.promisify is not a function
```

I'm using a polyfill for `util` so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error. Previously, I was getting similar errors referencing `events` and `process` that were resolved once I added the polyfill code to that file.

Opening the file that the error is referencing, `session.ts` under MongoDB's node_modules folder, the error seems to come from the first usage of the `promisify` function which is imported at the top of the file:

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
```

I've tried several different solutions for polyfilling that are mentioned on [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221740/how-do-i-polyfill-the-process-node-module-in-the-vite-dev-server), but I get the same error no matter what.

If anyone has any suggestions for solving this problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: This is XY problem. You seem to miss the point why it became necessary to polyfill all these things. "While attempting to connect to my MongoDB instance in Atlas" - you can't do this in browser app, end of the story.

Comment: @EstusFlask Would you mine elaborating please? I'm fairly new to the world of Vue so any guidance would be appreciated. I'm porting an old express app I made some years ago for practice so I may not be understanding some core principles completely.

Comment: Vue runs in a browser. Express runs in Node, if it does something else besides serving static files like Mongo, you still need both.